# How to optimize a sequence of multiple sed replacements?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, substitution

I am trying to clean-up some bash code from unnecessary repetiotions. Currently it looks like this (example values):

```
pattern1='aaa'
pattern2='bbb'
pattern3='ccc'

replacement1='XX'
replacement2='YY'
replacement3='ZZ'

tail $LOGS |
sed -e "s/${pattern1}/${replacement1}/g" \
    -e "s/${pattern2}/${replacement2}/g" \
    -e "s/${pattern3}/${replacement3}/g"
```

I have been thinking to put the patterns and replacements in 2 arrays:

```
pattern[0]='aaa'
pattern[1]='bbb'
pattern[2]='ccc'
# ...
replacement[0]='XX'
replacement[1]='YY'
replacement[2]='ZZ'
# ...
```

but I don't know how to merge the final result so that I can receive and run the final command like this:

```
tail $LOGS | sed -e "s/aaa/XX/g" -e "s/bbb/YY/g" -e "s/ccc/ZZ/g"
```

The idea is to be able to add more patterns and replacements later on in a clean and readable way, without having to modify the actual command that executes them.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You might consider switching to a more capable language, like perl or python.

Comment: @Kenster - as soon as I learn any of them :)

Answer (score 2):

Create an array of arguments in a loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
patterns=( 'a'
           'bcd'
           'x.*z'
)

replacements=( 'A'
               'BCD'
               'Y'
)

args=()
for (( i=0; i < ${#patterns[@]}; i++ )) ; do
    args+=(-e "s/${patterns[i]}/${replacements[i]}/g")
done

echo 'a bcd xyyyz' | sed "${args[@]}"
```

BTW: I'd rewrite the script in Perl once I got to this.

If you don't want to separate the patterns and replacements, use one array for both and increase the step:

```
#!/bin/bash
subst=( 'a'    'A'
        'bcd'  'BCD'
        'x.*z' 'Y'
)

args=()
for (( i=0; i < ${#subst[@]}; i+=2 )) ; do
    args+=(-e "s/${subst[i]}/${subst[i+1]}/g")
done

echo 'a bcd xyyyz' | sed "${args[@]}"
```

Comment: Question: I tried [this](https://pastebin.com/XgetVqJB) but it is outputting `asdfmm1mmm2mmm3mmm4m` (all alphabetic characters are red, the digits are not highlighted). What could be the reason? Also is there an more easy way to append elements to the `patterns` and `replacements`? In your code they are separated and when there are 50 replacements it would be very difficult to follow which couples with which.

Comment: @george: Reply to the second question in the update. Still checking the 1st one.

Comment: @george: You should post that as a separate question with the code included in the question.

Comment: the site is telling me "You can only post once every 90 minutes." :(

Comment: I think there is an error in your code. If I try `echo "${args[@]}"` it shows an additional `s///` for each pattern-replacement couple at the end and also the sed expressions are not in double quotes. Please update your code if possible, so that it works properly. Then I will mark it as the answer again.

Comment: I'll still be here in 90 minutes :-) I know the answer, but it's worth a full answer, not a comment. Just try `echo a | sed -e s/a/b/ -e s/b/c/`.

Comment: Could you please post the question and answer yourself instead of both of us waiting for 90 minutes?

Comment: Fixed, the `2*` was a mistake. You don't need the quotes in the output, they are removed by the shell when reading the input.

Comment: `echo 'asdf1234' | sed "${args[@]}"` now outputs a leading red `m` followed by bold white `asdf` followed by non-colorized `1234`. Please test with the pastebin code I gave. This really doesn't work as expected. There are no double quotes in `args`.

Comment: Learn how expansions work in a shell. No double quotes needed - sed doesn't see them when you enter them on the command line, they are removed by the shell.

Comment: Also, the reason why your code doesn't work is because the second pattern matches parts of the first replacement.

Comment: You may be right but the fact is: these same patterns and replacements work fine in the code as in my original question. As soon as they are put in your code they don't work. So I don't know what to do.

Comment: Also your code removes the `/g` matching, I don't know why. If it is there, additional `m` characters appear and the coloring is still messed up.

Comment: Ask a proper question with sample input so I can properly test what's going on.

Comment: I get exactly the same output from your old code, too.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44005505/sed-colorization-of-output-not-working-as-expected) is the new question