# Sed colorization of output not working as expected

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

reset=$(tput sgr0)
bold=$(tput bold)

red=$(tput setaf 1)
white=$(tput setaf 7)

pattern[0]='[0-9]'
replacement[0]="${white}${bold}&${reset}"

pattern[1]='[a-z]'
replacement[1]="${red}${bold}&${reset}"

args=()
for (( i=0; i < ${#pattern[@]}; i++ )) ; do
    args+=(-e "s/${pattern[i]}/${replacement[i]}/g")
done

echo "asdf1234" | sed "${args[@]}"
```

It outputs:

```
asdfmm1mmm2mmm3mmm4m
```

i.e. extra `m` characters are added and all alphabetic characters are red, the digits are not highlighted.

My desire is to have letters in red and digits in white. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

reset=$(tput sgr0)     # \001
bold=$(tput bold)      # \002

red=$(tput setaf 1)    # \003
white=$(tput setaf 7)  # \004

pattern[0]='[0-9]'
replacement[0]=$'\004\002&\001'

pattern[1]='[a-z]'
replacement[1]=$'\003\002&\001'

args=()
for (( i=0; i < ${#pattern[@]}; i++ )) ; do
    args+=(-e "s/${pattern[i]}/${replacement[i]}/g")
done

echo "asdf1234" | sed "${args[@]}" \
    | sed -e $'s/\001/'$reset'/g'  \
          -e $'s/\002/'$bold'/g'   \
          -e $'s/\003/'$red'/g'    \
          -e $'s/\004/'$white'/g'
```

Output on my system:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It might break if the input contains \001 etc.

Comment: Thanks. This works. However the `00x` codes make the code unreadable. I am willing to use the variable names to keep it readable. Can you please advise how to do that?

Comment: then just assigne `\ooo` to vars too. e.g.: `_red=$'\003'`

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it doesn't work is that the code for white and bold contains characters matched by the second pattern. `sed` applies all the patterns sequentially on each input line, e.g.

```
echo a | sed -e s/a/b/ -e s/b/c/  # Outputs "c".
```

What you need is to use a single expression with different replacements depending on the captured data, which is possiblee.g. in Perl:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use List::Util qw{ first };
use Term::ANSIColor qw{ color };


my $reset = color('reset');
my $bold  = color('bold');
my $red   = color('red');
my $white = color('white');

my (@pattern, @replacement);

push @pattern, '[0-9]';
push @replacement, "$white$bold";

push @pattern, '[a-z]';
push @replacement, "$red$bold";

my $regex = join '|', map "($_)", @pattern;

my $string = 'asdf1234';

$string =~ s/$regex/
    my $i = first { defined $+[$_] } 1 .. $#+;
    $replacement[$i-1] . "$+$reset"
    /ge;

say $string;
```

Just change the last part into

```
while (my $string = <>) {
    $string =~ s/$regex/
        my $i = first { defined $+[$_] } 1 .. $#+;
        $replacement[$i-1] . "$+$reset"
        /ge;

    print $string;
}
```

to make it process stdin or files given as arguments.

Comment: Perl to the rescue!

Comment: The question is for bash.

Comment: @george: Use the right tool for the job. Good luck.